# Scroll Views above RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have some view above my RecyclerView and i want to make them all scrollable as follows:

[image: Recyclerview]

And when i scroll, the toggle button should scroll as shown here:

[image: Scrolled]

My layout is as follows:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="Active"
                android:textOff="Completed"/>

        <fragment
                android:id="@id/Container_fromHomeActivity_BottomAppBarFragments"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:defaultNavHost="@bool/Navigation_NavigationHost_Default"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/bottomappbar_navigation"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_to_do"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@id/BottomAppBar_fromHomeActivity_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_dark"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottomappbar_main"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@id/FAB_fromHomeActivity_BottomAppBarAttached"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_dark"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/BottomAppBar_fromHomeActivity_Main"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But when i am trying to scroll, the toggle button is staying fixed on the screen. Only the recyclerview is scrolling behind the toggle button.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: This is unclear. can you show some real UI what you want?

Comment: I've update my question. Please help

Comment: I think you should hide show the toggle layout on scrolling on recyclerview.

Comment: You need functionality like Gmail' s Android app search bar. am I right?

Comment: I want it to scroll along with the recyclerview,not hide it ! Just like the newly designed Gmail app, the search bar scrolls with the recyclerview ...

Comment: Yes, it is doing the same thing. but they hide shows with animation so it looks like scrolling with recyclerview. They hiding it with animation on up scroll and showing on down scroll. You can check it by holding search bar half of the screen

Comment: Do you have some code that i can try ?

Comment: I don't have a code . but you can write it. Determine when the recyler scolling up and down and hide and show using animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine whether your recylerview is scrolling up or down. and the Hide/show and animate the toggle layout according to that scrolling.

**for example**

- Animation up for scrolling up and
- Animation down for scrolling down.

Here is my code for determining recylerviews up and down

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0 && toggelLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            //Hide
        } else if (dy < 0 && toggelLayout.getVisibility() !=View.VISIBLE) {
           //Show
        }
    }
});
```